# Reading multiple variables from a text file in python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a text file in the same directory labelled test.txt. It contains the following 3 lines:

```
10
3
5
```

The output this gives me is:

```
1
0

3
```

My code is below.

```
f = open('test.txt',"r")
test1 =(f.readline(1))
test2 = (f.readline(2))
test3 = (f.readline(3))
print (test1)
print (test2)
print (test3)
```

How would i go about making it pick up the full variables? Ie test1 = 10, test2=3, test3 = 5?
Very new to python :(

Comment: @MortezaIpo: What in heavens name does that gist have to do with what the OP is asking about?

Comment: @MartijnPieters as I said hope that be useful.

Comment: @MortezaIpo: sure, but it isn't. Not in any way that I can see. Perhaps you meant to link to a different gist (that link is over a year old), but in general a link to a gist without explanation isn't much help to begin with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see. you are right. it just has a simple description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to give `f.readline()` an argument at all:

```
test1 = f.readline()
test2 = f.readline()
test3 = f.readline()
```

otherwise you *limit* the number of characters read. `f.readline(1)` does *not* mean 'read line 1'; instead you say: 'read a line, but no more than 1 character should be read'.

Quoting from the [`IOBase.readline()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline):

> Read and return one line from the stream. If *size* is specified, **at most *size* bytes will be read.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: So simple, so elegant, so much noobiness on my part. Thanks for the explanation, i appreciate it!

Comment: Okay, heres my problem now. It can print the item happily, but when i recall the variable its giving me things like "10\n".

So i did a bit of research and i've been trying to use rstrip like the following, to strip out the \n when i call the variable later, however it ends up giving me a variable such as v1 = ''.

Not sure how to embed code into this so ill put it on paste bin at:
[Link](http://pastebin.com/GtVKqxur)

@Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user2809413: yes, the newline is included. You can strip that off; `test1.rstrip('\n')` would remove any newlines from the end of the string, for example (returning the altered string).

Comment: Sorry, not really sure how to implement that? Where does the test1 come from?

Comment: @user2809413: You used `test1` as a variable in your question.

Comment: ..It has been a long day...Thanks!